# How does one remember the difference between a "stalactite" and a "stalagmite"?

Tags: confusables, mnemonic

Is there a good mnemonic for remembering the difference between "stalactite" (hangs down) and "stalagmite" (points up)?

Comment: you are well loved. Four answers in under half an hour!

Comment: Either he's well-loved, or there's just a lot of mnemonic-loving people hanging around... :)

Comment: Yeah... sometimes it is hard to gauge one's own motives.

Comment: @J. M. - Touche! @Cerberus - Indeed, that is so!

Comment: Tights ('tites) come down.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is one from my secondary school geography teacher that I will never forget:

> *stala**c**tite --- **c**eiling*
>
> *stala**g**mite --- **g**round*
>
> Stala**c**tites hang from the **c**eiling; stala**g**mites rise from the **g**round.

As long as you remember what *c* and *g* mean in those words, you will never confuse them!

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Cool! Now that I think about it, I'm not too sure if this was from my teacher or from a classmate, but, whatever. It was still back in the good old days I learned about *yardangs*, *barchans*, and other features I'd never set my eyes on.

Comment: I learned stalactites cling to the ceiling; stalagmites grow from the ground. Reinforces that even more.

Comment: @Kate: Awesome! That's definitely more like it!

Answer (score 18):

Stalac **tites** have to hold on **tight**! (So they don't fall off...)

Answer (score 9):

Let me give you another mnemonic, closer to the heart of some:

> Stalactite = tit
>
> Stalagmite = you already remembered the tit one

This is how we remember it in Dutch, in which language it actually rhymes: stalactiet - tiet.

Comment: So you're saying the tits are up top, and everything else is incidental?

Comment: Hehe, well, basically... but tits generally hang down most of the time on most mammals.

Comment: I was VERY tempted to give this one the check mark... if only the British didn't have the expression "tits up" (which means things have gone horribly wrong, so "tits down" is presumably good... but that's a long chain for a mnemonic)

Comment: I guess you meant "closer to the heart" literally…

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: ah, telepathy! Same here, initially. While this is a funny mnemonic, this is one a teacher would have a really hard time pitching to a high school class without throwing decency to the wind!

Comment: Dunno about y'all, but my tits point horizontally. Except when I'm lying down, in which case they point *up*. So this mnemonic would, at best, be useless; at worst, it would cause me to always get it wrong.

Comment: Perhaps the crucial point to some mnemonics is to accept them at face value because they seem right at the moment of acceptance, even though one might later realize that they were nonsense - but then they'd have already done their job. Whatever the case, to go into the matter a bit more: I believe that gravity affects tits by exerting a downward force on them when they are pointing horizontally - the normal situation -, so that perhaps it could be said that they hang down after all - especially at middle age, if I am not misinformed. Please erase, this is going on too far.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Arg I was going to leave this alone, but yes I meant this "closer to the heart" both ways. Never mind.

Answer (score 8):

Stalactites hold tight to the ceiling, and Stalagmites might grow to meet them.

Comment: +1 Ah, I've also heard this one. Nice!

Comment: That's the one I've always used.

Answer (score 6):

"When mites crawl up, they pull their tights down." That's how I always remembered it...

Comment: The saying I was taught was similar. It was something about pulling tights up, so I just remember that you pull tights up and that's where stalactites are.

Answer (score 6):

Look to the shape of the capital letter: stalag M ite vs stalac T ite

Answer (score 5):

Stalagmites **might** reach the roof. Stalactites have to hold on **tight**!

Comment: You **might** trip over a stalagmite.

Answer (score 2):

We learned at school:

> The tights come down and the mites crawl up!

Well it was the 1960s…

Answer (score 1):

Stalactite has the "lact" root in it meaning "milk", because, well, hanging from the cave roofs, they look like the thing on women's body that gives milk. All I need to do is think about lactating women.

Comment: I was right: spelunking IS a dirty word.

Comment: Is that true?  Or just a handy mnemonic.

Answer (score 0):

Stalactites are st(l)uck tight to the ceiling.

Stalagmites are the other one.

Answer (score 0):

'Stalagmites' contains the German word 'Stalag' (camp) which is better located on the floor of the cave. Stalactites are the other deposits on the ceiling of the cave.